# How to check color is black

Tags: colors

Hello，I have a  **bytebuffer** size is 4,which contain **rgba** value.
How to quickly check the **bytebuffer** value is black? How t

```
int luma = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b; 

if (luma < 40) {
 // pick a different colour
}
```

Comment: You need to tell (and tag) what programming language you're talking about.

Comment: rgb is balck when all those elements are zero and the alpha is not relevant in this case